# Singer in nightclub scene

Tags: harry-potter, character-identification, fantastic-beasts

In the nightclub scene in "Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them," a singer sings a jazz song (apparently it was a big break for the real-world singer, but that's another story.) In-universe, who is the bald female singing that song (apparently titled "Blind Pig?") Is it a young goblin? A half-human half-goblin (or half-elf) or what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [screenplay](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Fantastic-Beasts-Where-Find-Them/dp/1338109065) indicates that she's a goblin.

> *A glamorous goblin jazz singer croons on a stage full of goblin
> musicians, smoky images wafting from her wand to illustrate her
> lyrics. All is dingy and shabby, an atmosphere of menacing fun.*

As to the identity of the actual *singer,* we can turn to Pottermore

> *It’s probably the sultriest song from the Fantastic Beasts soundtrack.
> We bring you, for the first time in full, ‘Blind Pig,’ written by J.K.
> Rowling and Mario Grigorov and performed by singer-songwriter Emmi.*
>
> <sup><sub>[Exclusive: Pottermore debuts jazz song from the Fantastic Beasts soundtrack](https://www.pottermore.com/news/exclusive-debut-of-blind-pig-jazz-song-from-fantastic-beasts-soundtrack)</sub></sup>

The actress portraying the goblin in the film is [Aretha Ayeh](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm6422972/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t54) via [mo-cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_capture)

Comment: man, goblins certainly look different in FB than they did in HP. In FB they look like poorly-done CGI house-elves that are of unusual size. :/